# Find the ratio of the radii

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, elementary-number-theory, circles, triangles

> [Euclid Contest April 2015 Problem 8B](http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2015/2015EuclidContest.pdf)
>
> I cannot type it as it has a diagram along with it, which might mess up my interpretation.

This was a tough problem, I cannot solve it completely. **HINTS ONLY**

I believe it has something to do with Homethecy of the circle. And the scaling factor.

But I am not sure how to use homethecy with circles, what can I do? **Hints please.**

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Draw mid-perpendicular of YZ, also perpendicular lines of two circles from this line to XZ. Then consider 3 similar triangles, and we have

$$\frac{\sqrt{a^2-\left(b/2\right)^2}-R}{R}=\frac{a}{b/2}=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-\left(b/2\right)^2}-(2R+r)}{r}.$$

Simplify the equality, then you could get the answer.

BTW, the condition $b<2a$ is not necessary, since for any triangle, summation of any two edges is larger than the other, i.e. $|YZ|<|XZ|+|XY|$.